# CSS specificity of a nested HTML element that doesn't have any explicitly declared styles

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to find the explanation for this CSS cascading/inheritance rule.  Given the example below, I would have thought the em tag would be colored #000000, but I was told that the em tag would be colored #ff0000.

I am used to CSS specificity rules for declared selectors, but I never really thought about elements nested inside other elements that have styling.  Where in the W3C spec describes this behavior? (or any other source)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
     <div>Hello, this is an <em>important</em> announcement.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* { color: #ff0000; }
div {color: #000000; }
```

Comment: Are you asking for specificity rules or inheritance rules? It's quite simple in this case: If not *explicitly* assigned, elements inherit some rules from their parent. But here you explicitly assign the color via the wildcard selector.

Comment: You may also use cascading as for example "div em { ... }" - all em's in all div's will have these properties applied. You may nest how many levels you wish and you may also use id selectors (#), classes(.), etc.

Comment: I think my problem is that * is the universal selector and applies to the em tag, as others have noted.  That overrides the inheritance of the style from div.

I don't use * much, so I never made that association that it has a specificity and would match the em.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `*` which selects all the element in your document, so if we elaborate this, it actually means

```
div {
   color: red;
}

em {
   color: red;
}

/* And so on... */
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr8rM/)

It will apply red color as you've specified red color for all the elements

But your `div` is black as you are using element selector which is more specific than `*` selector which is least specific

so if you want your `em` to be black, you need to use [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr8rM/1/)

```
em {
   color: inherit;
}
```

Or to be more specific

```
div em {
   color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: My mistake is not realizing that *, being the universal selector, is a selector and would target the em tag.  Thanks for the code example and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It will only inherit the `color` from its parent when there is no matching rule that specifies a different `color`.

`*` matches `em`, so the color will be `#ff0000`. `*` is a very special selector, it matches every element. In your example, it would basically be equivalent if you wrote:

```
em { color: #ff0000; }
div {color: #000000; }
```

Comment: It is called a `universal selector` and not a *very special selector* ;)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Speak quietly, it is not a good idea to hurt the feelings of a star :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I decided to give Mr. Alien the accepted answer credit, since he had set up code examples explaining my misunderstanding of the universal selector.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with nesting. You just have two rules. One says that `div` elements have `#000` colour, another says that all elements have `#f00` colour. The first rule doesn't apply to your `em` (since it's not a `div`), the second does; it overwrites the default `inherit` value with `#f00`, that's all.

Speaking about specificity and nesting, specificity values all over the path are simply summed.